# Kotlin: cann't recognize two strings as equals

Tags: kotlin

I have to implement unit converter in educational purpose so to say. It converts length, weight and temperature units. When user enters `1 kg to ounces` the programm returns
`1.0 kilogram is 35.27399072294044 ounces` and so on. When input/output units are unknown the code returns `Conversion from ??? to ??? is impossible`. For example, user's input  `1 knn to feet` and the code returns
`Conversion from ??? to feet is impossible`. Issues starts with the  temperature units. For degrees Celsius, the user can input "degree Celsius", "degrees Celsius", "celsius", "dc", or "c". The same is for Fahrenheit. When I use "dc" or "c" or "celsius", everything works perfect, but when I use "degree Celsius", "degrees Celsius" or "degree Fahrenheit" as input/output units (`5 degree celsius to k`), I get
`Conversion from degrees Celsius to kelvins is impossible`.
Why is it so? Why doesn't input string "degrees Celsius" and the same string in *when (inputUnits)*-block perceived as equals and how I can fix it?

Here is the code:

```
fun plural(unit: String): String {
    val plurals = listOf("grams", "kilograms", "milligrams", "pounds", "ounces", "meters", "kilometers", "centimeters",
        "millimeters", "miles", "yards", "feet", "inches", "degrees celsius", "degrees fahrenheit", "kelvins")

    if (unit in plurals) return unit

    when (unit) {
        "m", "meter" -> return "meters"
        "km", "kilometer" -> return "kilometers"
        "cm", "centimeter" -> return "centimeters"
        "mm", "millimeter" -> return "millimeters"
        "mi", "mile" -> return "miles"
        "yd", "yard" -> return "yards"
        "ft", "foot" -> return "feet"
        "in", "inch" -> return "inches"
        "g", "gram" -> return "grams"
        "kg", "kilogram" -> return "kilograms"
        "mg", "milligram" -> return "milligrams"
        "lb", "pound" -> return "pounds"
        "oz", "ounce" -> return "ounces"
        "degree celsius",  "celsius", "dc",  "c" -> return "degrees Celsius"
        "degree fahrenheit",  "fahrenheit", "df",  "f" -> return "degrees Fahrenheit"
        "kelvin",  "k" -> return "kelvins"
        else -> return "???"
    }
}

fun main() {
    print("Enter what you want to convert (or exit): ")
    var tag = false
    var inputVal: Double = 0.0
    var inputType: String
    var command = readLine().toString().lowercase()
    var inputUnitName = "???"
    var outputUnitName ="???"

    while (command != "exit") {
        val inputs = command.split(" ")
        //val inputVal = inputs[0].toDouble()
        //val inputVal: Double
           try { inputVal = inputs[0].toDouble()
            } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                //println("Parse error")
               tag = true
            }
        var inputUnits = inputs[1]
if (inputs[1].lowercase() == "degree" || inputs[1].lowercase() == "degrees" &&
    inputs[1].lowercase() == "celsius" || inputs[1].lowercase() == "Fahrenheit"){
    inputUnits = inputs[1] + " " + inputs[2]
    println(inputUnits)
}

        var outputUnits = inputs.last()
        if (inputs[inputs.size - 1] == "degree" || inputs[inputs.size - 1].lowercase() == "degrees" &&
            inputs.last().lowercase() == "celsius" || inputs.last().lowercase() == "Fahrenheit"){
            outputUnits = inputs[inputs.size - 1] + " " + inputs.last()
        }

        var intermediateVal: Double = 0.0
        val outputVal: Double

        when (inputUnits) {
            "m", "meter", "meters" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "meter" else "meters")
                inputType = "distance"
                intermediateVal = inputVal
            }
            "km", "kilometer", "kilometers" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "kilometer" else "kilometers")
                inputType = "distance"
                intermediateVal = inputVal * 1000
            }
            "cm", "centimeter", "centimeters" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "centimeter" else "centimeters")
                inputType = "distance"
                intermediateVal = inputVal * 0.01
            }
            "mm", "millimeter", "millimeters" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "millimeter" else "millimeters")
                inputType = "distance"
                intermediateVal = inputVal * 0.001
            }
            "mi", "mile", "miles" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "mile" else "miles")
                inputType = "distance"
                intermediateVal = inputVal * 1609.35
            }
            "yd", "yard", "yards" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "yard" else "yards")
                inputType = "distance"
                intermediateVal = inputVal * 0.9144
            }
            "ft", "foot", "feet" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "foot" else "feet")
                inputType = "distance"
                intermediateVal = inputVal * 0.3048
            }
            "in", "inch", "inches" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "inch" else "inches")
                inputType = "distance"
                intermediateVal = inputVal * 0.0254
            }
            "g", "gram", "grams" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "gram" else "grams")
                inputType = "weight"
                intermediateVal = inputVal
            }
            "kg", "kilogram", "kilograms" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "kilogram" else "kilograms")
                inputType = "weight"
                intermediateVal = inputVal * 1000
            }
            "mg", "milligram", "milligrams" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "milligram" else "milligrams")
                inputType = "weight"
                intermediateVal = inputVal * 0.001
            }
            "lb", "pound", "pounds" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "pound" else "pounds")
                inputType = "weight"
                intermediateVal = inputVal * 453.592
            }
            "oz", "ounce", "ounces" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "ounce" else "ounces")
                inputType = "weight"
                intermediateVal = inputVal * 28.3495
            }
            "celsius", "dc",  "c", "degree сelsius", "degrees сelsius" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "degree Celsius" else "degrees Celsius")
                inputType = "temper"
                //intermediateVal = inputVal * 28.3495
            }
            "degree Fahrenheit", "degrees Fahrenheit", "fahrenheit", "df",  "f" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "degree Fahrenheit" else "degrees Fahrenheit")
                inputType = "temper"
                //intermediateVal = inputVal * 28.3495
            }
            "kelvin", "kelvins", "k" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "kelvin" else "kelvins")
                inputType = "temper"
                //intermediateVal = inputVal * 28.3495
            }
            else -> {
                intermediateVal = inputVal
                inputType = ""
            }
        }

        when {
            inputType == "distance" && outputUnits in listOf("m", "meter", "meters") -> {
                outputVal = intermediateVal
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "meter" else "meters")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "distance" && outputUnits in listOf("km", "kilometer", "kilometers") -> {
                outputVal = intermediateVal / 1000
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "kilometer" else "kilometers")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "distance" && outputUnits in listOf("cm", "centimeter", "centimeters") -> {
                outputVal = intermediateVal / 0.01
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "centimeter" else "centimeters")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "distance" && outputUnits in listOf("mm", "millimeter", "millimeters") -> {
                outputVal = intermediateVal / 0.001
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "millimeter" else "millimeters")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "distance" && outputUnits in listOf("mi", "mile", "miles") -> {
                outputVal = intermediateVal / 1609.35
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "mile" else "miles")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "distance" && outputUnits in listOf("yd", "yard", "yards") -> {
                outputVal = intermediateVal / 0.9144
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "yard" else "yards")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "distance" && outputUnits in listOf("ft", "foot", "feet") -> {
                outputVal = intermediateVal / 0.3048
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "foot" else "feet")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "distance" && outputUnits in listOf("in", "inch", "inches") -> {
                outputVal = intermediateVal / 0.0254
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "inch" else "inches")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "weight" && outputUnits in listOf("g", "gram", "grams") -> {
                outputVal = intermediateVal
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "gram" else "grams")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "weight" && outputUnits in listOf("kg", "kilogram", "kilograms") -> {
                outputVal = intermediateVal / 1000
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "kilogram" else "kilograms")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "weight" && outputUnits in listOf("mg", "milligram", "milligrams") -> {
                outputVal = intermediateVal / 0.001
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "milligram" else "milligrams")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "weight" && outputUnits in listOf("lb", "pound", "pounds") -> {
                outputVal = intermediateVal / 453.592
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "pound" else "pounds")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "weight" && outputUnits in listOf("oz", "ounce", "ounces") -> {
                outputVal = intermediateVal / 28.3495
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "ounce" else "ounces")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "temper" && inputUnitName.lowercase() in listOf("degree celsius", "degrees celsius",
                "celsius", "dc",  "c") && outputUnits.lowercase() in listOf("degree Fahrenheit",
                "degrees Fahrenheit", "fahrenheit", "df", "f") -> {
                outputVal = inputVal * 9 / 5 + 32
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "degree Fahrenheit" else "degrees Fahrenheit")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "temper" && inputUnitName in listOf("degree Celsius", "degrees Celsius",
                "celsius", "dc",  "c") && outputUnits in listOf("degree Celsius", "degrees Celsius",
                "celsius", "dc",  "c") -> {
                outputVal = inputVal
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "degree Celsius" else "degrees Celsius")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "temper" && inputUnitName in listOf("degree Celsius", "degrees Celsius",
                "celsius", "dc",  "c") && outputUnits in listOf("kelvin", "kelvins", "k") -> {
                outputVal = inputVal + 273.15
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "kelvin" else "kelvins")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "temper" && inputUnitName in listOf("degree Fahrenheit",
                "degrees Fahrenheit", "fahrenheit", "df", "f") && outputUnits in listOf("degree Celsius", "degrees Celsius",
                "celsius", "dc",  "c") -> {
                outputVal = (inputVal - 32) * 5 / 9
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "degree Celsius" else "degrees Celsius")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "temper" && inputUnitName in listOf("degree Fahrenheit",
                "degrees Fahrenheit", "fahrenheit", "df", "f") && outputUnits in listOf("degree Fahrenheit",
                "degrees Fahrenheit", "fahrenheit", "df", "f") -> {
                outputVal = inputVal
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "degree Fahrenheit" else "degrees Fahrenheit")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }

            inputType == "temper" && inputUnitName in listOf("degree Fahrenheit",
                "degrees Fahrenheit", "fahrenheit", "df", "f") && outputUnits in listOf("kelvin", "kelvins", "k") -> {
                outputVal = (inputVal + 459.67) * 5 / 9
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "kelvin" else "kelvins")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "temper" && inputUnitName in listOf("kelvin", "kelvins", "k") && outputUnits in
                    listOf("degree Fahrenheit", "degrees Fahrenheit", "fahrenheit", "df", "f") -> {
                outputVal = inputVal * 9 / 5 - 459.67
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "degree Fahrenheit" else "degrees Fahrenheit")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "temper" && inputUnitName in listOf("kelvin", "kelvins", "k") && outputUnits in
                    listOf( "degree Celsius", "degrees Celsius", "celsius", "dc", "c") -> {
                outputVal = inputVal - 273.15
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "degree Celsius" else "degrees Celsius")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            inputType == "temper" && inputUnitName in listOf("kelvin", "kelvins", "k") && outputUnits in
                    listOf( "kelvin", "kelvins", "k") -> {
                outputVal = inputVal
                outputUnitName = (if (outputVal == 1.0) "kelvin" else "kelvins")
                println("$inputVal $inputUnitName is $outputVal $outputUnitName")
            }
            tag == true -> {println("Parse error")
            }
            else -> {
                println("Conversion from ${plural(inputUnits)} to ${plural(outputUnits)} is impossible")
            }
        }
        println()
        print("Enter what you want to convert (or exit): ")
        command = readLine().toString().lowercase()

    }

}
```

Comment: I did some debuging and when the input unit is "degree Celsius", "degrees Celsius" or "degree Fahrenheit", ```when (inputUnits) {"celsius", "dc",  "c", "degree сelsius", "degrees сelsius" -> {
                inputUnitName = (if (inputVal == 1.0) "degree Celsius" else "degrees Celsius")
                inputType = "temper"
            }``` is always skipped and went directly for else-block ```        else -> {
                intermediateVal = inputVal
                inputType = ""
            }```

Comment: I don't know if that is the actual issue, but you are mixing capitalization, sometimes you use `degree(s) celsius` and sometimes `degree(s) Celsius`, same for fahrenheit.

You would not have this issue if you defined the lists you compare with once and reuse them, it would also save you a massive amount of repeated code.

Comment: **Please** define your units with their alternative names as instances of some class instead of mixing the plain strings with business logic, it's so repetitive and error prone as written now.

Comment: @somethingsomething, thank you for your anwer, but unfortunately mixing capitalization is not the isuue. I tried just lowercase and got the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue 1:**
You are chaining your logic incorrectly.

Pseudo code version of what you basically have:

```
if (it=="degree" || it=="degrees" && it=="celsius" || it=="fahrenheit")
```

And what you need to do:

```
if ((it=="degree" || it=="degrees") && (it=="celsius" || it=="fahrenheit"))
```

By directly chaining your conditionals, your logic basically is:

```
if (it=="degree" || (it=="degrees" && it=="celsius") || it=="fahrenheit")
```

because `&&` has precedence over `||` the same way `*` is evaluated before `+` in arithmetic.

**Issue 2**
You are comparing the lowercase version of your text to capitalized "Fahrenheit", so it can never be true. You should use `"fahrenheit"`.

**Issue 3**
You are using `inputs[1]` for all four conditions, when I think you mean to use `inputs[2]` for the second two conditions, because you're checking whether the third word is Fahrenheit or Celsuis.

**Issue 4**
You have an invisible unicode U+1089 character in some of your Strings. Since it is a rare character from Burmese, the IDE and StackOverflow do not render it at all, but I can see it by printing the UTF codes (`println("degree сelsius".map { it.code })`). It looks very similar to the degree symbol °, so I suspect you copy-pasted it from somewhere. To fix your code, delete and retype all your strings involving the word "degree".

**Side note:** Your code has a ton of duplication. Your program could be less error prone and take up about a third as many lines if you defined a class for each type of Unit that lists all the names it can go by and conversion formula to some base unit. If you find yourself copy-pasting any literal String, you have a design issue that is likely to cause bugs.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've chanaged the logic as your said 
'''if ((inputs[1].lowercase() == "degree" || inputs[1].lowercase() == "degrees") &
    (inputs[1].lowercase() == "celsius" || inputs[1].lowercase() == "fahrenheit")){
    inputUnits = inputs[1] + " " + inputs[2]
} '''
but I'm still getting the similar error
'''Enter what you want to convert (or exit): 5 degree celsius to k
Conversion from ??? to kelvins is impossible'''

Comment: I found two more issues with your code. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I've fixed the issues you said about but unfortunately the issue with two-words units hasn't gone. 
`Enter what you want to convert (or exit): 5 degree celsius to k
Conversion from degrees Celsius to kelvins is impossible

Enter what you want to convert (or exit): 5 celsius to k
5.0 degrees Celsius is 278.15 kelvins`. I really don't get why I don't get into this branch `when (inputUnits) {` when inputUnits = degree celsius

Comment: You're going to love this. You have an invisible unicode U+1089 character in some of your Strings. Since it is a rare character from Burmese, the IDE and StackOverflow do not render it at all, but I can see it by printing the UTF codes (`println("degree сelsius".map { it.code })`). It looks very similar to the degree symbol °, so I suspect you copy-pasted it from somewhere. To fix your code, delete and retype all your strings involving the word "degree".